# Which Supported ABIs to select for Google Play

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, abi

My Android app has support for 4.1+, and I want to keep the apk as small as possible. Is it safe to use the default `armeabi-v7a` or do I need to support more?

Also wondering the same if I have an app supporting Android 2.3+

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can use `armeabi-v7a`. It suits most phones out there.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a better explanation of "most phones"?

Comment: Some phones do use a x86 or x86-64, they tend to be more popular in Asian regions. The Asus Zen Phone is off the top of my head.

Comment: You need to check arm64-v8a and x86_64 too to support 64 bits devices. This is even required for the Google Play now.